# Not Hitting Delete Route in Node / MongoDB

Tags: jquery, mongodb, express

I'm building an app and have no issues with my get or post routes to work, but I'm hung up on this delete route.

I've set up my front end javaScript like this. The first function receives the data and dynamically creates HTML using a template literal.

```html
//Populates Storms From Database
  fetch("/api/data/storm", {
    method: "get",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  })
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      data.forEach(storm => {
        console.log(storm.stormName);

        const stormContainer = `
      <div class="item">
        <div class="content">
          <div class="header">
            <a class="storm-val" value="${storm._id}">${storm.stormName}</a>
          </div>
            February 2021
        </div>
        <form>
          <i type="submit" value="${storm._id}" class="delete-storm trash alternate outline icon" action="/api/data/storm/${storm._id}"></i>
        </form>
      </div>
      `
        $('#stormsEl').append(stormContainer);

      });
    });
```

The next function is meant to delete a storm from the database. I realize there is some truly horrific code in here but it does give me the id of the clicked storm.

```html
$(document).on("click", '.delete-storm', (evt) => {
    let oldStormId = evt.currentTarget.parentNode.parentNode.childNodes[1].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].getAttribute("value")
    // oldStorm = oldStorm.replace(/ /g, "-").toLowerCase();
    console.log(oldStormId)
    // console.log($(this).siblings(".content").children(".header").children(".storm-val"))
    fetch(`/api/data/storm:${oldStormId}`, {
      method: "delete",
      // body: JSON.stringify(newEmployeeData),
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
      })
  })
```

I use express to connect my routes to hit a controller here, which works to post and get storms.

```html
const router = require("express").Router();
const {
    createStorm,
    getStormWithShifts,
    createShift,
    getAllShifts,
    getAllStorms,
    deleteStorm
} = require('../../controllers/shiftController');

//all routes in this file start with /api/data/

router.route('/storm').post(createStorm).get(getAllStorms);
router.route('/storm').get(getAllStorms);
router.route('/storm/:stormId').delete(deleteStorm);
router.route('/storm/:stormId').get(getStormWithShifts);

router.route('/shift').post(createShift).get(getAllShifts);


module.exports = router;
```

This is where no matter what I try I can't seem to get a connection.

```html
async deleteStorm(req, res) {
    console.log("hello")
    await Storm.findOneAndRemove({ _id: req.params.stormId })
    .then(dbStormData => {
      if (!dbStormData) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'No storm with this id!' });
      }

      res.json({ message: 'Storm successfully deleted!' });
      
    })

  }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the delete path you are calling on the frontend is incorrect. On the express router you are using `/storm/:stormId` but not passing the second `/` on the frontend. Try changing `/api/data/storm:${oldStormId}` to `/api/data/storm/${oldStormId}`.